# Should I leave the peel in citrus sugar?

Tags: storage-method, sugar

I made [citrus sugar](http://www.ehow.com/how_4732752_make-citrus-sugar.html) a couple of weeks ago and am planning on giving portions of it to friends. I figure they can use it baking, tea, margarita glass sugar, etc.

My question is should I remove the pieces of lemon/orange peel before I package it up for my friends or should I include the peel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would leave the peel in. It can continue to improve the flavor, and makes it look like citrus sugar instead of just plain sugar (important for a gift). Be sure to include a note that it should be used within a few weeks, though.

Comment: And stored in the fridge.